# LSTM after Embedded Layer - Value Error: Isn't symbolic tensor?

Tags: python

for some reason I can not add an LSTM-Layer to my model:

```
embed_size=8
LSTM=Sequential()
LSTM.add(Embedding(max_words,embed_size,input_length=max_len))
LSTM.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer'))
LSTM.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
...
```

I get the following error:

```
      3 LSTM.add(Embedding(max_words,embed_size,input_length=max_len))
----> 4 LSTM.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer'))
      5 LSTM.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
      6 LSTM.add(Dropout(0.1))

C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    438             # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    439             # with the input_spec set at build time.
--> 440             self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    441 
    442             # Handle mask propagation.

C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    283                                  'Received type: ' +
    284                                  str(type(x)) + '. Full input: ' +
--> 285                                  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
    286                                  'should be tensors.')
    287 

ValueError: Layer sequential_6 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'int'>. Full input: [30]. All inputs to the layer should be tenso
```

What does it mean? Are there some dimension issues between my Embedding and LSTM?

For some reason, if I use following "notation", things seem to workout normally:

```
inp = Input(shape=(800, )) #maxlen=200 as defined earlier for 
embed_size = 256
x = Embedding(20000, embed_size)(inp) #maximum dictionary ###outputs a 3D-Sensor
x = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer')(x)
```

Any idea whats the problem?

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an issue in your namespace, you overwrite the imported LSTM layer.
Change `LSTM` to `lstm` in your model name.

```
from keras import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Embedding,LSTM, GlobalMaxPool1D
embed_size=8
max_len = 1000
max_words = 10
lstm=Sequential()
lstm.add(Embedding(max_words,embed_size,input_length=max_len))
lstm.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer'))
lstm.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
```

Works fine

**Detailed explanation for newcomers:**
The import statement sets a local reference called `LSTM` that is a class implementing a Keras layer. Then, it is overwritten in the statement `LSTM=Sequential()`. Now the name `LSTM` is an instance of a Keras sequential model. Finally, in the statement `LSTM.add(LSTM(...))` the inner operation `LSTM(..)` is a call to the model, implemented by `__call__` method of the `Sequential` class (this feature is native in python). So the throwed error says *sequential_6 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor...* , which means that an instance of the `Sequential` class (which was automatically name *sequential_6* by the framework) is called, with an input that is incompatible with the implementation. This assertion is in the `__call__` implementation of the `Sequential` class.

Comment: oh boy, that was a silly mistake :) still getting used to python syntax. THY

Comment: @KostaS. I noticed that you have never, ever accepted any answer to your questions. I strongly encourage you do start accepting answers by clicking the green checkmark. This one seems to have solved your problem, so why not accept it?